# WordPress: Use button to add class to a div element

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I am working on a WordPress website and I want to add a button that once clicked will expand all fields of the accordion. 
But the problem is that I can only assign a CSS class to the Button (theme developer only allows me to do that).
once the user clicks on the button, can I use CSS to execute a jQuery (or any other language that will do the trick) file that will contain the code to expand all sections of the accordion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is quite a powerful styling language, but that's all it is actually designed for: styling elements. It isn't really going to be capable of executing any type of Javascript or related client-side code on its own.

You have a few options depending on how much you are able to actually change about the site.

**If you can add / change Javascript**

If you can actually add a small script to the site, then this should become fairly trivial. You would simply need to add a CSS class to your specific button and then wire up an event handler to capture the click event in jQuery to perform your action :

```
<button class='your-special-button'>Click Me!</button>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('.your-special-button').click(function(){
             // Your button was clicked, do something...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Depending on the functionality, you could potentially handle this inline via an `onclick` event as well :

```
<button onclick='DoSomethingHere();'>Click Me!</button>
```

**If you cannot add / change Javascript**

Depending on your exact functionality, it may be possible to handle this purely through CSS if the markup is in a state that supports it to create a basic accordion [as seen here](http://codepen.io/anzjoy/pen/bahAv).

There are a variety of tutorials out there and different ways to implement it, consider a quick search for "pure CSS accordion" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thank Rion this works. Now the only thing I need to figure out is how to use jQuery to find a div element with a particular class and add another class to it.

Comment: Easy. `$('.class-you-are-looking-for').addClass('class-to-add');`

Comment: Would this replace the class or would it add another class to the element?

Comment: This would only add the class, it wouldn't make any changes to the existing one. If you wanted to do that, you would use something like `$('.class-you-want-to-replace').attr('class','your-replacement-class');`